# Create a function to explode dataframe on column

Tags: python, explode

I have written some code to explode a df on a column.

```
df=df.assign(col=df['col'].str.split(',')).explode('col')
```

I now wanto make a function doing the same:

```
def explode(df,col_ind,col:str):
df=df.assign(col_ind=df[col].str.split(',')).explode(col)
return df

explode(df5,beans,'beans')
```

I do get the following error:

> NameError: name 'beans' is not defined
>
> Blockquote

Does someone know how to improve the function such that it works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call a `bean` variable that isn't defined. To define a kwarg from a string, you have to pass it as a kwarg dictionary with `**`:

```
def explode(df, col_ind, col:str):
    df=df.assign(**{col_ind : df[col].str.split(',')}).explode(col)
    return df

explode(df5, 'beans', 'beans')
```